# why is variance so famous that it appears in almost half of the probability textbook?

Tags: probability, statistics, math-history

why is variance so famous that it appears in almost half of the probability textbook?

What is its significant history so that a statistical model would appear in such textbooks and what does it help to evaluate probability?

In another word, what useful properties makes variance to get a lot of coverage in some probabilty textbook?

Comment: why are the Kardashians famous?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking why variance is important, or are you asking what qualifies a probability distribution to get a lot of coverage in a textbook?

Comment: Only half? Did you do a sample? That seems low.

Comment: Variance is a measure of how spread out a distribution is, and of all the measures of spread I've seen, it's the easiest to compute and has the most useful properties.  I wouldn't say that variance is "famous" so much as foundational.  You seem unhappy that variance is as ubiquitous as it is.  Do you feel the same way about mean?

Comment: "The variance of the number of times variance showing up in a randomly chosen statistics book should give us a glimpse of why variance is so famous." True?

Comment: Don't say that. Mean will be very mean to variance if that's true.

Comment: What is this other half of textbook I haven't heard of?

Comment: Because Chebyshev's Theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure there are many reasons related in one way or another to the stability of systems. I'll give you an example that I'm working on. Imagine you use a cloud computing system. You log on to a server and you need to wait for some time to access your information. This is a queueing network where 'jobs' (customers) get in the queue upon arrival and wait for the 'server' (actual server bottleneck).

Image you have two options: one server has mean waiting time of 5 min and variance of 100, and second has mean 10 and variance of 0.1. What does it mean? The mean of waiting time/queue length of server 1 is lower, but if you want to join it you pretty much don't know how long you need to wait for: it can be 1 minute, it can be 15 min, 30 seconds, 40 mins etc. Essentially, mean is a bad estimate of how long you need to wait.

Contrary to that, waiting time of the second server is a much better estimate, because variance is very small: it is probably going to be something like 9.5 minutes, 10.1 minutes. etc.

So variance says something about the stability of the system.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a kind of off-the-wall idea.

A Gaussian random variable, whether scalar or vector, is naturally described, and completely determined, by its mean and variance. This is not the case for every distribution we might consider, but it's true for the Gaussian. And since the mean in many models is so often zero, the variance is arguably the most important of the two measures for study.

The Gaussian distribution happens to be the most important, or at least the most common, distribution that statisticians (or really, anyone dealing with random variables) consider. I can think about a couple of reasons why this is the case. For one thing, the Central Limit Theorem means we really are likely to encounter Gaussian distributions a lot. Many processes have fundamental underlying non-Gaussian variables, but they feed them into averaging processes whose outputs are therefore Gaussian (or nearly so).

Even if the CLT isn't saving our proverbial backsides, and the distribution we're trying to study *isn't* Gaussian, we often like to go ahead and pretend it is. And this is my second, more cynical reason: we use Gaussian methods because *we know how*.

For instance, least squares is maximum likelihood estimation when the residuals are expected to be Gaussian i.i.d. But we use least squares *all the time* in situations where we can't make that assumption reliably. There are a handful of other ML problems that are tractable (two-sided exponential and uniform come to mind). But even then, we might just go with least squares because, well, that's what the software on our computers knows how to compute.

That's not to say we *should* do this, and it certainly gets people in trouble sometimes to use Gaussian techniques on non-Gaussian statistics. But we do.

So to sum up, perhaps the reason that variance is so important is because it *is* the most important measurement in many cases; and we *treat* it like it is sometimes even when it's not.

Comment: I think this is all very excellent motivation for why we should care about standard deviation, but the the OP (and I!) might be better served with a bit about why we would ever be concerned with the square of it; after all, we're not frequently concerned with $\pi^2$.

Comment: Really! Interesting. About all I care about is the square of it. Different experiences here.

Comment: And if you're working with multivariate distributions, it's kind of hard to work with the standard deviation. Sure, it can be done, but you're probably going to stick with variance until you have to do otherwise.

Comment: Huh. I don't have any experience with multivariate stats, so I'll take your word for it :)

Comment: Well, I will say this, the standard deviation is the square root of the variance---*and not the other way around*. In order to calculate the standard deviation, you have to calculate the variance *first*, and take the square root. There's no way around that. So in a very real sense, the variance is more fundamental.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by it being a "statistical model." The way I've always looked at it is, variance is a probabilistic property of a distribution. It just happens to be extremely useful in statistics, since it is a standard parameter for some important distributions.